# finding the nearest number in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sorted list of numbers. I want to search the array for a number (lets call it searchVal). So the line of code below works fine if the number is in the array.

```
var sPos = $.inArray(searchVal, MyArray);
```

However if it is not in MyArray I want to select the next biggest number, i.e

I'm searching for 8 in the list below I would like it to return 10.

```
4, 5, 6, 10, 11
```

I am new to javascript and wondering what the best way to achieve this is? I have  seen a filter could be used where any number >= to 8 is returned and then take the min number from this filtered list. Or is this a case when I should make use of the reduce function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using jquery, how would i find the closest match in an array, to a specified number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561275/using-jquery-how-would-i-find-the-closest-match-in-an-array-to-a-specified-num)

Comment: Another possible duplicate : [Javascript find closest number in array without going under](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25061543/javascript-find-closest-number-in-array-without-going-under)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) on sorted array.

> The `find()` method returns the *value* of the *first* element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise `undefined` is returned.

```js
console.log([13, 4, 6, 5, 10, 11].sort((a, b) => a > b).find(x => x > 8));
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the array is sorted you can use

```
var num = MyArray.find(x => x > 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

For unsorted data, you could take the absolute delta of an item and check with the delta of last item and return the one with smaller delta.

```js
var array = [5, 4, 11, 6, 10],
    find = 8,
    nearest = array.reduce((a, b) => Math.abs(a - find) < Math.abs(b - find) ? a : b);
    
console.log(nearest);
```

Answer (score -2):

Hi you use the map function to determine the distance to 8.

```
var array = [4, 5, 6, 10, 11];
var distanceArray = array.map(function(element){
var distance = 8-element
if(distance < 0){
distance = distance * -1;
}
return distance;
})
```

then you got [4,3,2,2,3]. use Math.min

```
var minimum = Math.min(...distanceArray);
```

Now you got 2 as minimum. now found the position

```
var position = distanceArray.indexOf(minimum);
```

now you can see whats number is nearest,

```
var nearest = array[position];
```

got you 6....

Comment: OP says he would like it to return `10` if hes search number is `8`

Comment: Im sorry. I did not see that