# How can I change a var to the nearest number?

Tags: javascript, rounding

I have two numbers wich can change, like x1 and x2. Then I also have an other number what is random but always between x1 and x2, like z. What I want to do is change z to the nearest x.

Sooo if I give you guys an example:

Input:

```
x1 = 12.24
x2 = 346.92
z = 274.45
```

Output:

```
z = 346.92
```

z is now 346.92 because that is the nearest number for z. This is what I am trying to do in Javascript. I thought there was no command for and you have to do it with just some math. I really have no idea how to do that... But there are you!

Thnx for all your help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584902/get-closet-number-out-of-array

Comment: So in your example above, z is 12.24 50% of the time and 346.45 50% of the time?

Comment: How is this anything to do with rounding a number??

Comment: @ChrisC No, 274.45 is closer to 346.92 than it is to 12.14

Comment: @ChrisC Yes because z is random

Comment: Does [my response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28883285/3974585) helped you ? Its telling you which one is the nearest, and Z is a random number so you can try it multiple times just by running the code.

I removed the JQUERY document ready, and it is now only javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
z = (Math.abs(z-x1)<Math.abs(z-x2))?x1:x2;
```

If you're sure x1 < x2, then:

```
z = ( (z-x1) < (x2-z) ) ? x1 : x2;
```

Comment: Thnx this is working fine!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oa4r24bc/4/)
With [**Math.abs**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_abs.asp)(z - x1) and [**Math.abs**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_abs.asp)(z - x2) you get the number between both values. Then you check if the first difference is bigger than the second.

```
x1 = 12.24;
x2 = 346.92;
z = Math.floor((Math.random() * 346) + 1);
z_ = z;
if (Math.abs (z - x1) < Math.abs (z - x2)){
  z = x1;
}     
else{
  z = x2
}
alert(z_ + " is closer to : "+ z);
```

Edit : Added a [**random** **number**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp) every time you run so you can see exactly how it works

Comment: Corrected that, thought it would be simplier to put the code into a document ready, but you are right the user didnt tag jquery

Comment: Took the liberty of anglicizing your answer. This is an english-language website.

Comment: Yeah indeed, thanks for reminding, sometimes in code lines belgium is coming back :(

Answer (score 0):

```
z = Math.round((z - x1) / (x2 - x1)) * (x2 - x1) + x1;
```

Whether `x1` is greater than `x2` or vice versa, this will consistently move `z` to the closer of the two.

How does it work?

```
(z - x1) / (x2 - x1)
```

Find the difference between `z` and `x1` as a ratio to the difference between the two extrema.

```
Math.round((z - x1) / (x2 - x1))
```

Choose an extreme (1 or 0) based on proximity.

```
Math.round((z - x1) / (x2 - x1)) * (x2 - x1)
```

Multiple that extreme (1 or 0) by the difference between the two extrema.

```
Math.round((z - x1) / (x2 - x1)) * (x2 - x1) + x1;
```

Add the difference to `x1`, guaranteeing that the result is equivalent to either `x1` or `x2`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
z = (Math.abs(x1-z)>(Math.abs(x2-z)) ? x2 : x1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just calculate the difference by substracting Z from x1, and x2:

```
if( (z - x1) < (x2 - z)){
  z = x1;
}else{
  z= h2;
}
```

If the values may get negative .. use `Math.abs(z-x1)` , `Math.abs(x2-z)` to get the ABSOLUTE value.

Answer (score -1):

If z is random and evenly distributed:

```
z = Math.random() > 0.5 : x1 ? x2;
```

Comment: OP said it was 3 minutes ago.