# Get closest number of array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want get closest number in the array. It have to be like this:

For example I have an array: `[1, 3, 7, 15, 40, 55, 70, 80, 95]`

Number variable: `numberD1`;

If numberD1: 8 - The closest number can be only 7. Not 15.

If numberD1: 54 - It can be only 40. Not 55.

I mean, i want closest number like this. But what I selected the number mustn't be higher than the closest number(like `Math.floor()` function).

Sorry for my Bad English. I hope i told my problem as good.

Comment: What have you done to try and solve this yourself?

Comment: check array forEach function, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: I using this function. And i found this on stackoverflow.
`function closest(num, arr) {
    var mid;
    var lo = 0;
    var hi = arr.length - 1;
    while (hi - lo > 1) {
        mid = Math.floor((lo + hi) / 2);
        if (arr[mid] < num) {
            lo = mid;
        } else {
            hi = mid;
        }
    }
    if (num - arr[lo] <= arr[hi] - num) {
        return arr[lo];
    }
    return arr[hi];
}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get closest number out of array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584902/get-closest-number-out-of-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

```js
// sample array
a = [1, 3, 7, 15, 40, 55, 70, 80, 95]

// get right number
function getClosest(a, numberD1) {
    return numberD1 - a.reduce(function(closest, v) {
        return numberD1 >= v ? Math.min(numberD1-v, closest) : closest;
    }, 1e100);
}  


// output result
document.write(8 + ' => ' + getClosest(a, 8));

document.write('<br>');

document.write(54 + ' => ' + getClosest(a, 54));
```

Comment: Oh, i forgot say that. numberD1 can be float value. I tried numberD1 as float. Your function returned "-1e+100". Is this function only for integer values?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it correctly, you're looking for something like this, if the array is sorted:

```
var list = ...
var numberD1 = ...
var result = null;
for (var i = 0; i < list.length(); i++){
    if (list[i] <= numberD1)
        numberD1 = list[i];
}
return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your array is sorted, I would think in theory you could just do a search for the specified value, then return the value preceding it?

Iterate through with a search, then return numberD1[key - 1];

Ah, I just saw you are searching for any arbitrary value, I'm sure you can still figure out a way around that. Just search for the closest value above it then do what I showed.

Comment: That array keys, can be random numbers. Example [5,98,2]. So it be irregular. I use closest function as that but i want what closest number higher than numberD1 .
Function:
`
function closest(num, arr) {
    var mid;
    var lo = 0;
    var hi = arr.length - 1;
    while (hi - lo > 1) {
        mid = Math.floor((lo + hi) / 2);
        if (arr[mid] < num) {
            lo = mid;
        } else {
            hi = mid;
        }
    }
    if (num - arr[lo] <= arr[hi] - num) {
        return arr[lo];
    }
    return arr[hi];
}
`

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to invent `Array.prototype.insert()` which inserts a series of items starting from the given index value and returns the mutated array. It is needed for functional JS. However the `insertNum` function subject to this question does not mutate the original array.

```js
Array.prototype.insert = function(i,...rest) {
  this.splice(i,0,...rest)
  return this
}

var arr = [1, 3, 7, 15, 40, 55, 70, 80, 95];
var insertNum = (a,n) => a.slice(0)
                          .insert(a.reduce((p,c,i) => {var d = Math.abs(n-c);
                                                       p[0] > d && (p[0] = d, p[1] = n > c ? i+1 : i);
                                                       return p} ,[Infinity,0])[1],n);

document.writeln("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(insertNum(arr,8)) + "</pre>");
document.writeln("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(insertNum(arr,54)) + "</pre>");
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

EDIT - Took care of getting a number which is lower if possible

```
function closest(num, array){
var closest = Infinity
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        if (closest < num){
            if (array[i] < num && array[i] > closest)
                closest = array[i]
        }
        else if (array[i] < num || array[i] < closest)
            closest = array[i]
    return closest != Infinity? closest :null
}
```

Comment: This isn't be useful for my issue. Because closest number must be higher than numberD1. On that function, it can be higher, for example:
var numberD1 = 5;
var array = [1, 2, 6, 7];
The closest number must be 2. Not 6.

Comment: This function should work as you wish, and supports float numbers as well. Oh, seems it's too late :)

Comment: No matter :) I found a function. It working with jQuery. `function closest(goal, theArray) {
    var closest = null;
    $.each(theArray, function () {
        if (this <= goal && (closest == null || (goal - this) < (goal - closest))) {
            closest = this;
        }
    });
    return closest;
}  ` That working for me :)