# Find the next highest number in array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of numbers and a value. I'd like to find the numbers around the value. The most important is the highest value but I need both.

```
var array = [2,4,5,8,11];
var value = 9;
```

The result I need should be : 8 and 11.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: The Internet is flooded with solution to such problem...

Comment: How is this a jQuery question?

Comment: I didn't find a solution to my problem, that's why I ask. I did it when datas in array are always incrementing by 1. But for my question, I didn't find a solution.
And I'm trying to do that in jQuery.

Comment: It seems you don't understand the purpose of Stack Overflow or jQuery...

Comment: I suggest you start by learning how to write for-loops and comparisons in Javascript, and leave jquery aside.  There are numerous sites and books devoted to teaching Javascript.

Comment: @PSport: you can tweak this answer to get both solutions http://stackoverflow.com/a/19277804/1719752

Comment: Ok thanks for this post !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This help you :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        
        var array = [2,4,5,8,11];
        
        var value = 9;
        
        var min,max;
        
        fun();
        
        function fun() {
            
            var sortArray = array.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
            
            for(var i=0; i<sortArray.length;i++) {
                
                if (sortArray[i] < value)
                    min = sortArray[i];
                
                if (sortArray[i] > value)
                    max = sortArray[i];
            }
            
            alert(min + " , " + max);
        }
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed thanks. I can use it and adapt it perfectly to my need.

Answer (score 4):

Just write a simple for-loop searching for each of the values.

So for example:

```
function findNumbers(arr, num){
    var low = num + 1; //largest number lower than num, set initial value above num
    var high = num - 1; //smallest number higher than num, set initial value below num
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++){
         if(arr[i] > low && arr[i] < num){
             low = arr[i];
         }
         if(arr[i] < high && arr[i] > num){
             high = arr[i];
         }
    }

    //optional check to see if low/high exists
    if(low > num){
        low = -1; //not found
    }
    if(high < num){
        high = -1; //not found
    }
    return [low,high];

}
```

and there you go. This works whether or not `arr` is sorted.

Comment: Ok thanks, understood !

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your question looks like you are still learning jquery.However I am sure you will get good suggestions here.

Here is an example with your test case,I am leaving the explanation on you so that you can study each line and learn.

```
var myArray = [2, 4, 5, 8, 11];
var myValue = 9;

function BiggerThan(inArray) {
  return inArray > myValue;
}

function LesserThan(inArray) {
  return inArray < myValue;
}    

var arrBiggerElements = myArray.filter(BiggerThan);
var nextElement = Math.min.apply(null, arrBiggerElements);
alert(nextElement);

var arrLesserElements = myArray.filter(LesserThan);
var prevElement = Math.max.apply(null, arrLesserElements);
alert(prevElement);
```

Comment: Ok thank you, I'm going to analyse that.