# Shortest way to compare your score to three ranges in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I have the following code:

```
function display_message() {
    var low = data.result[0].max; //returns 30
    var medium = data.result[1].max; // returns 60
    var high = data.result[2].max; // returns 100

    // mypoints are 67 for example
    if(mypoints > low) {
        if(mypoints > medium) {
            alert('You got a high score');
        } else {
            alert('You got a medium score');
        }
    } else {
        alert('You got a low score');
    }
}
```

This code works fine. I compare my average score to the standard *low / medium / high score*.

Low score: `0-30 points`
Medium score: `31-60 points`
High score: `61-100 points`

My question though is how to make my code a bit prettier? I am not sure if the code is considered as clear and efficient.

Any opinions would be much appreciated, thank you

Comment: use ternary conditions for that

Comment: Hello @Halcyon, it was a mistake while I was writing the question. Fixed it

Comment: ternary is best option for shortest way

Comment: Aside from the medium/high mixup I don't see anything I'd change in this code. Maybe call `alert` once with a `message` variable. This code is about as clear as it's going to get. _ternary_ operators for more than one comparison gets really messy.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584902/get-closest-number-out-of-array

Comment: I think there's something like codereview.codeexchange or something like that i can't check it right now. You may get the answer you're searching for there.

Comment: @user5014677: Indeed. shieldcy, after [checking their guidelines](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), this might be a better fit for CodeReview.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's probably a better fit for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com); check [their guidelines](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to ensure your post is on-topic there.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answers. I didn't know the existence of "CodeReview", sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for the if else with low, just check from smallest to highest.

```
if (mypoints <= low) {
  //low msg
} else if (mypoints <= medium) {
  //medium msg
} else {
  //high msg
}
```

or you can go the opposite direction and check for the highest first with greater than

Answer (score 1):

You could use a condition without nested conditions.

```
if (mypoints > medium) {
    alert('You got a high score');
} else if (mypoints > low) {
    alert('You got a medium score');
} else {
    alert('You got a low score');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, we iterate over the various values that make up the score range. The loop will iterate over each score range **in turn**, meaning you need to have the lowest score first and highest score last. We then save score name against `myscore` to be alerted out at a later point.

This approach allows for expandability - you can add as many score ranges in the middle without having to add any more if/else blocks.

```js
let data = {result: [{max: 30}, {max: 60}, {max: 100}]},
    mypoints = 67;

function display_message() {
  let score_range = {
      low: data.result[0].max, //returns 30
      medium: data.result[1].max, // returns 60
      high: data.result[2].max // returns 100
    },
    myscore = 'fail';

  for (var score in score_range) {
    if (score_range.hasOwnProperty(score)) {
      if (mypoints > score_range[score]) {
        myscore = score;
      }
    }
  }
  alert('You got a ' + myscore + ' score!');
}
display_message();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store the messages in an array, and find the correct index like so:

```js
function display_message() {
    var low = 30,
        medium = 60,
        rank;
    mypoints = 67; // for example
    rank = ['low', 'medium', 'high'][+(mypoints > low) + +(mypoints > medium)];
    console.log('You got a ' + rank + ' score');
}

display_message();
```

The magic is in the unary plus operator which converts booleans returned by comparisons to 0 or 1 accordingly. It's also easy to include more rankings if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
mypoints < low ? alert("you get low score") : (mypoints < medium ? alert("you get medium score") : alert("you get high score"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `switch` statement

```
function display_message() {
    var low = data.result[0].max; //returns 30
    var medium = data.result[1].max; // returns 60
    var high = data.result[2].max; // returns 100

    switch (true) {
      case mypoints > medium:
        alert('You got a high score');
        break;
      case mypoints > low:
        alert('You got a medium score');
        break;
      default:
        alert('You got a low score');
    }   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a function which takes the score and an array as an argument with the different levels and their names `{"score": 30, "text": "You got a low score"}` and then just loop that and output what is closest to what you sent in and return the matching text.

Example:

```
var myScore = 50,
    scoreIntervals = [{
            "score": 30,
            "text": "Low score"
        },{
            "score": 60,
            "text": "Average score"
        },{
            "score": 100,
            "text": "High score"
        }];

function evaluateScore(score, scoreIntervals) {
    var output = scoreIntervals[scoreIntervals.length - 1].text;
    $.each(scoreIntervals, function(key, val) {
        if(score <= val.score) {
            output = val.text;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return output;
}

console.log(evaluateScore(myScore, scoreIntervals));
```