# Find closest to the number inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have below array

```
const floorPerDayMilestones = [25, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 175, 200]
```

From the frontEnd user enters any number say it is

```
const number = 136
```

I need to find closest to the number but the lesser one.
So the output should be `125`

Even if the number is `149` the output should be `125`

How can I do this. I tried many way but could get the answer.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Share some code what you tried?

Comment: Your problem statement is unclear. What should be returned for a value such as 12, 125, or 300?

Comment: Walk through the array until you find a bigger number, then take the one before that.

Comment: You could do

`Math.floor(x / 25) * 25;`

To get the nearest multiple of 25 (rounded down) to your number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's sorted in ascending order like in the question this should work.

```
const floorPerDayMilestones = [25, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 175, 200];
const number = 136;

function findClosest(arr, num) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    if (arr[i] > num) {
      return arr[i - 1];
    }
  }
}

console.log(findClosest(floorPerDayMilestones,number));
```

Comment: @Andreas was a typo, I was returning the index not the element, I think it works now

Comment: @Profer if you find an answer suitable you can mark it as accepted and the question can be closed. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.reduce` for this

```js
const floorPerDayMilestones = [25, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 175, 200]

function getClosestNumber(d) {
  return floorPerDayMilestones.reduce((a, b) => b <=d && a < b ? b : a, 0 )
}

console.log(getClosestNumber(135) || 'No lesser number available')

console.log(getClosestNumber(149) || 'No lesser number available')

console.log(getClosestNumber(22) || 'No lesser number available')
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should look at this: [get closest number out of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584902/get-closest-number-out-of-array)

And in your foreach, save your closest number in a var. Then check if your number is bigger than the one in your array . if yes, take your last var, else continue your foreach

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
const floorPerDayMilestones = [25, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 175, 200];
    
const number = 136;
    
    
const nextLesser = floorPerDayMilestones.reduce((nl, curr) => (curr <= number) && (curr > nl) ? curr : nl , 0)

console.log(nextLesser)
```

Used [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: Its give me `100` when i put `number`  `125`. I need `125`

Comment: @Profer try again, I changed the code a bit. All that was needed to do is change `<` to `<=`

Comment: You are welcome! Consider selecting the best answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the array in ascending order and then find the index of number that is immediately higher than `number` then one position less of that value will be the immediate number that is less than `number`

```js
const floorPerDayMilestones = [25, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 175, 200]
const number = 136;
floorPerDayMilestones.sort((a,b)=> a-b);
var index = floorPerDayMilestones.findIndex(val => val>number);
var num = floorPerDayMilestones[index-1];
console.log(num);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also filter out numbers greater than given and select max from this subset.

```js
const floorPerDayMilestones = [25, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 175, 200]

const number = 136

const filtered = floorPerDayMilestones.filter(el=>el<=number);

console.log(Math.max(...filtered))
```

Or, if you're already using lodash (only in this case - don't import lodash just to use solution below), you can do it with `maxBy`. `maxBy` treats numbers greater than `number` as `null`.

```js
const floorPerDayMilestones = [25, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 175, 200]

const number = 136

let result = _.maxBy(floorPerDayMilestones, el=>el<=number?el:null);

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Cool! But I believe this is two set of operations vs one when using reduce.

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev Right, it's rather more readable than efficient, but there were already 2 answers with `reduce`

Comment: Its give me `100` when i put `number`  `125`. I need `125`

Comment: @Profer I understood "*closest to the number but the lesser one*" as `<`, but if you need lesser or equal then it's enough to replace `<` to `<=`. I've updated my code

Comment: @barbsan Oh no, why suggesting lodash for such a simple task. Lodash should actually be deprecated nowadays, native features are good.

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev because OP has tag lodash, so propably already uses it

Comment: @barbsan Oh ok, fair.

Answer (score 1):

With lodash you could use [`_.sortedIndex`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#sortedIndex):

```js
const numbers = [25, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 175, 200]

const closestNum = (arr, n) => {
  let index = _.sortedIndex(arr, n)
  return arr[index] == n ? arr[index] : arr[index-1]
}

console.log(closestNum(numbers, 135))  // 120
console.log(closestNum(numbers, 160))  // 150
console.log(closestNum(numbers, 180))  // 175
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

With JS you can simply use [`Array.reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight):

```js
const numbers = [25, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 175, 200]

const closestNum = (arr, n) => arr.reduceRight((r,c) => !r && c < n ? c : r, 0)

console.log(closestNum(numbers, 135))  // 120
console.log(closestNum(numbers, 160))  // 150
console.log(closestNum(numbers, 180))  // 175
```

Since it will start from the right side all you care about is to find the first number less than your argument `n`.

You could also do [`Array.reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) and then just [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) (use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) if you do not want to `mutate` the array):

```js
const numbers = [25, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 175, 200]

const closestNum = (arr, n) => arr.reverse().find(x => x < n)

// To not mutate use `Array.from`
// const closestNum = (arr, n) => Array.from(arr).reverse().find(x => x < n)

console.log(closestNum(numbers, 135))  // 120
console.log(closestNum(numbers, 160))  // 150
console.log(closestNum(numbers, 180))  // 175
```