# How to find closest lower value in array angular 6?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an array of objects where I need to find closest lower value from that array based on some value or current value in angular 6, I have already tried but its showing undefined.

### app.component.html

```
<button (click) ="getPrev()">Previous Value</button>
```

### app.component.ts

```
declare var require: any;
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent{
    arrayVal:any;
    currentVal : any;
  title = 'projectchart';
  public array = [{"id":1},{"id":3},{"id":5}];


  getPrev(){
     this.currentVal = 5;
     this.arrayVal= this.array; 
     let number = this.arrayVal.reverse().find(e => e <= this.currentVal);
     console.log(number);
  }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [get the closest number out of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584902/get-closest-number-out-of-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could find the nearest closet number as below

```js
let arr = [
    { "id" : 1 },
    { "id" : 3 },
    { "id" : 5 }
];

let referenceNumber = 4;

let nearestLowest = arr.reduce((acc, val) => {
    if(val['id'] < referenceNumber && val['id'] > acc)
        acc = val['id'];
    return acc;
}, Math.max());

console.log(nearestLowest);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have id in your array so this -

```
 let number = this.arrayVal.reverse().find(e => e.id <= this.currentVal);
```

will not be undefined

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to:

```
 getPrev(){
 this.currentVal = 5;
 this.arrayVal= this.array; 
 let number = this.arrayVal.reverse().find(e => e.id <= this.currentVal);
 console.log(number);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one.**

```
  getPrev(){
     this.currentVal = 5;
     this.arrayVal= this.array; 
     let number = this.arrayVal.reduce((prev, current) => {
       return (Math.abs(current.id - this.currentVal) < Math.abs(prev.id - this.currentVal) ? current : prev);
     })
     console.log(number.id);
  }
```

**[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8gqqly)**

Answer (score 0):

If your ids can be negative numbers, you can go with this:

```js
getClosestLowerIdElement(value: number, array: Array<{[key: string]: number}>) {
    const v = {id: value};
    return array.reduce((acc, a) => acc = (
        (acc.id === undefined || Math.abs(v.id - a.id) < Math.abs(v.id - acc.id) || 
            acc.id > v.id) && a.id < v.id) ? a : acc, {id: undefined});
  }
```

And you can use it like this:

```js
idArray = [{id: 1}, {id: -30}, {id: -5}, {id: 7}, {id: 9}, {id: 11}, {id: 21}];

...

console.log(this.getClosestLowerIdElement(0, this.idArray)); // prints {id: -5}
```

If there's no number lower than the value passed to the `getClosestLowerIdElement` method, you'll get `{id: undefined}`

See the demo on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t7x71u?file=src/app/app.component.ts)