# jQuery dynamic number comparison

Tags: jquery, select, numbers, range

I have a form with 1 input and 1 select with options (example: 2500, 3000, 4000, 5000)

I need to be able to:

- Create an array for each options in the select
- When I enter a value in the input field (number)
- Determine between each select.value is the text.value
- Fake click on the select.value which is the "min" range.

Example :

- input = `2800` > Fake click on `selection.option(2500)`
- input = `3200` > Fake click on `selection.option(3000)`

Where it's tricky, that's the select has different value on each page.

At this time, to test:

```
<input min="0" max="7000" class="largeur" value="" type="number" placeholder="" required="">

<select id="longueur" class="" name="attribute_longueur" data-attribute_name="attribute_longueur" data-show_option_none="yes">
  <option value="">Choisir une option</option>
  <option value="2508" class="attached enabled">2508</option>
  <option value="4785" class="attached enabled">4785</option>
</select>
```

```js
$(".largeur").keyup(function() {
  console.log('keyup');
  $('#longueur option[value="2508"]').prop('selected', true); // Only to test fake click on value 2508
});
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why do you need to 'fake click' on the `select`? Do you instead mean that you want to select the `option` element with the closest value to that entered?

Comment: Maybe I'll modify to a fake click... Because the click on option trigger another element to be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create the array of values you can use `map()`. From there you simply need to read the value which is typed in to the `number` input, then determine which value in the array is closest to that. The latter can be done following the code provided by @JoeGrund in [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19277804/519413). Then it's just a matter of setting the `val()` of the `select`. Try this:

```js
var $select = $('#longueur');
var values = $select.children('option').map(function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  return value.trim() == '' ? null : parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
}).get();

$('.largeur').on('input', function() {
  var typedValue = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
  var closestValue = values.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return (Math.abs(curr - typedValue ) < Math.abs(prev - typedValue ) ? curr : prev);
  });
  $select.val(closestValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input min="0" max="7000" class="largeur" value="" type="number" placeholder="" required="">

<select id="longueur" class="" name="attribute_longueur" data-attribute_name="attribute_longueur" data-show_option_none="yes">
  <option value="">Choisir une option</option>
  <option value="2508" class="attached enabled">2508</option>
  <option value="4785" class="attached enabled">4785</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is absolutely marvelous !!!!! Thank you very much Rory !

Comment: In fact, I think I didn't well explain the situation. I need, when input valie is between 100 and 200... take 200 value.
for 331 > must be 400...

It's not always round values (100 / 200 ...), it's strange value like 2785 / 4210 / 5320....

Comment: I solved it with this :

https://codepen.io/dataprojekt/pen/wvvmpBO?editors=1010