# How to properly use array.prototype.filter() rather than .map()

Tags: javascript

I have this object with values

```
const source = {
  '10': 3,
  '15': 3,
  '20': 2.5,
  '25': 2.5,
  '30': 2,
  '35': 2,
  '40': 2,
  '45': 2,
  '50': 2,
  '55': 1.5,
  '60': 1.5,
  '70': 1.5,
  '80': 1.5,
  '90': 1.5,
  '100': 1,
  '125': 1,
  '150': 1,
  '200': 0
}
```

And a term I am attempting to fit:

```
const parm = 36.5
```

I want to retrieve the pair which has the **key** closest to the parm value.

I tried using map:

```
result = Object.keys(source).map((x) => {if (weight - x > 0) { return ({[x]: source[x], diff: (weight - x)}) }} )
```

Which is good, except that it returns `undefined` for non matches.

I found a question asking about `map()` returning undefined and an answer suggested filter() is more appropriate.

```
result = Object.keys(source).filter((x) => {if (weight - x > 0) { return ({[x]: source[x], diff: (weight - x)}) }} )
```

`.filter()` **is** more appropriate except that it simply returns the keys, and I can't track which key was the best fit for the pair I want.

I'm a little stumped here. I may be approaching the problem wrong, so suggestions on the approach are also welcome.

I was thinking `Math.min()` would isolate the best answer, but I'm not seeing how to use it as I can't compare the filtered values to each other to take the min.

**UPDATE**
Adapting the solution in the question I'm duplicating I came up with this:

```
let index
Object.keys(source).forEach((item) => {
  let dist = weight - item
  if ((dist > 0 && dist < index) || index === undefined) {
    index = item
  }
})

console.log(source[index])
```

And there was my answer.

The answer from @atomh33ls is more elegant though. It also reduces the complexity to log(N) right?

I forgot `reduce()` would resolve my problem with accessing a previous element of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35000557/1461850), you can use `reduce`:

```js
const source = {
  '10': 3,
  '15': 3,
  '20': 2.5,
  '25': 2.5,
  '30': 2,
  '35': 2,
  '40': 2,
  '45': 2,
  '50': 2,
  '55': 1.5,
  '60': 1.5,
  '70': 1.5,
  '80': 1.5,
  '90': 1.5,
  '100': 1,
  '125': 1,
  '150': 1,
  '200': 0
}
let target = 36.5
let key= Object.keys(source).reduce((prev, curr) => Math.abs(curr - target) < Math.abs(prev - target) ? curr : prev);
result = {key:key,value:source[key]}
console.log(result)
```

Comment: How were you able to answer? I wanted to post my translation of that solution as the answer I used. Your use of reduce is elegant though. I did not realize it could be used for this problem.

Comment: This was perfect. I forgot that reduce() has the access to previous. It was wriggling the back of my head that it was possible. I need to code a lot more.

Comment: Dang. So simple.

Comment: I like it as an elegant solution, but when I tried it on a different data set it did not produce the expected results. My interpretation works. I'm not sure what's wrong with the way I implemented the code.

Comment: I didn't realize the reducer/callback needed to return a value in order to populate previousValue. Discovered this using a different algorithm where I used reduce.