# The best way to get num's area without use if or switch

Tags: javascript, algorithm

If the input is a number (e.g) 78.

Now,
0 to 60, belongs to RANK C,
61 to 90, belongs to RANK B,
91 to 100, belongs to RANK A.

Then, if we **can't directly to compare 78 and area.** like `if (61<num && num<90)` or `switch case` or any conditional,it's not allowed!
how can we find the rank number 78 belongs to ?

> Here is my solution

I now have a solution to the problem, I use the Array.

```
let recordMap = [60, 90, 100]
recordeMap.push(78)
recordMap.sort((a,b)=>a-b)
```

now, the array is `[60, 78, 90, 100]`,
then I just need to know 78's index, `recordMap.findIndex(e=>e==78)` I can to known 78 is RNAK B.

**Is there a better solution?**

Comment: How about Ternary operator ? Allowed ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the closest number out of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584902/get-the-closest-number-out-of-an-array)

Comment: Ternary operator just like if else , you can't direct judgment 78 and 61~90

Comment: [Get the closest number out of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584902/get-the-closest-number-out-of-an-array)
My answar is to use array.it''s different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take conditional opererators.

```js
const
    getRank = value => value <= 60
        ? 'C'
        : value <= 90
            ? 'B'
            : 'A'

console.log(getRank(78)); // B
```

An approach with an array by taking the index and adding an offset for getting a character.

```js
const
    getRank = value => String.fromCharCode(
        [90, 60, 0].findIndex(v => value > v) + 65
    );

console.log(getRank(91)); // A
console.log(getRank(90)); // B
console.log(getRank(28)); // C
```

Comment: The second way is very well!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regex to check if number is in some range.

```
(?:[0-9]|[1-5][0-9]|60) --> Rank 'C'
(?:6[1-9]|[78][0-9]|90) --> Rank 'B'
(?:9[1-9]|100) --> Rank 'A'
```

For example:

```js
console.log("Test if 78 is in range 61-90");
console.log(/^(?:6[1-9]|[78][0-9]|90)$/.test(78));
```

Comment: even if this works, it is not useful if you need to maintain the values. the other draback is, you need still a condition to check the result of the test.

Comment: True, but i think i any case you will have at least one condition. Another optimization of that one could be putting those Regex as object value and the keys would be A, B, C And than you could iterate through the object. (Just a suggestion) @NinaScholz

Answer (score -1):

I now have a solution to the problem, I use the Array.

```
let recordMap = [60, 90, 100]
recordeMap.push(78)
recordMap.sort((a,b)=>a-b)
```

now, the array is `[60, 78, 90, 100]`,
then I just need to know 78's index, `recordMap.findIndex(e=>e==78)` I can to known 78 is RNAK B.

Comment: Either this is an answer, then there shouldn't be a question. Or _"is there a more optimized solution"_ is the actual question then this "answer" should be in the question.

Comment: If you want to get another rank, you'd have to remove the number . Why not `recordMap.findIndex(a => (a - number) > 0)`? You don't have to push the number and sort.