# How do you find the closest number to k in a given list in python?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to find the closest number in a list to a certain variable,
I have managed the first step,

```
def closest(lst, K):
    
    return lst[min(range(len(lst)), key = lambda i: abs(lst[i]-K))]

lst = [1.25, 1.35, 2.12, 2.35, 2.45, 3.44, 4.01, 4.56, 4.85, 5.02, 5.56, 6.52,7.56]

K = 4.36

print(closest(lst,K)) #Output: 4.56
```

the second step however has been a challenge. i wanted now to be able not only to find the
closest number, to a variable but also to make it more specific such that the closest number
should also be less than the variable. The output for that function above is 4.56, I would however like to get an
output of 4.01.

Any advice on how I can alter my code to come but that output?

Comment: Make the distance `float(Inf)` if it's in the wrong direction?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584902/get-the-closest-number-out-of-an-array/8584940#8584940 for a good start.

Comment: Hi @SamuelByegon if any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is a little different, you can try this:

```
def closest(lst, K):
    j={k:abs(k-K) for k in lst if k<K}
    return min(j,key=j.get)
lst = [1.25, 1.35, 2.12, 2.35, 2.45, 3.44, 4.01, 4.56, 4.85, 5.02, 5.56, 6.52,7.56]

K = 4.36

print(closest(lst,K))
```

Here is how the logic works:

If you notice, when you want to get a particular number which is closest to some number, you will notice that the difference is the least among other numbers.

So using this logic, it is creating a dictionary where the key is the number and the value is the difference of the number and the other number which is provided as a parameter. You will also notice that I have used `abs`. That is used to find the **absolute value** of the number. If I don't use that, then the numbers smaller than the one provided will have difference that are negative numbers. So, they of course will be less than positive numbers.

And the statement `return min(k,key=j.get)` tells that `min` function should get the minimum value from the dictionary `j` based on the values of `j`

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, could you explain what line 2 is and what it does, i have never seen a function like that.

Comment: @SamuelByegon Please wait for a minute. I will edit the answer

Comment: @SamuelByegon Please check it now

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, it now makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Does this achieve what you want?

```
def closest(lst, K):
    
    return lst[min(range(len(lst)), key = lambda i: K - lst[i] if K >= lst[i] else float('inf'))]

lst = [1.25, 1.35, 2.12, 2.35, 2.45, 3.44, 4.01, 4.56, 4.85, 5.02, 5.56, 6.52,7.56]

K = 4.36

print(closest(lst,K)) #Output: 4.01
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. what does the last part do "else float ('inf')"? A further explanation will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @SamuelByegon `float("inf")` set a variable with infinitely large value, therefore making it not a candidate for closest element if  `K - lst[i] < 0`

Answer (score 0):

You can just filter out all elements in `lst` that are greater than `K`. Try this:

```
def closest(lst, K):
    less_than_k = [x for x in lst if x < K]
    return less_than_k[min(range(len(less_than_k)), key=lambda i: abs(less_than_k[i] - K))]


lst = [1.25, 1.35, 2.12, 2.35, 2.45, 3.44, 4.01, 4.56, 4.85, 5.02, 5.56, 6.52, 7.56]
K = 4.36

print(closest(lst, K))  # Output: 4.01
```

Comment: This is brilliant! I hadn't even thought of that.

Comment: Thank you! Feel free to upvote and accept my answer so others will benefit as well.

Answer (score 0):

see below

```
import sys

lst = [1.25, 1.35, 2.12, 2.35, 2.45, 3.44, 4.01, 4.56, 4.85, 5.02, 5.56, 6.52, 7.56]

K = 4.36
delta = sys.float_info.max
close_number = sys.float_info.max
for num in lst:
    if num < K:
        if K - num < delta:
            delta = K - num
            close_number = num

print(close_number)
```

output

```
4.01
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, could you also accompany some side notes on what each line of the code does?